# How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, dos, x86-16, bios

This is purely academic, out of date, out of curiosity. Let's back to 1990s, before the Windows, when real-mode DOS programs were common.

The BIOS remapped the INT 08H+ for their own interrupt handler, for instance, int 10H for VGA MODE switch, int 13H for hard driver.  ([Table of software-interrupt numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call#Interrupt_table))

But, as we can see in Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals, we can know that there are also many real-address exception that can cause interrupt.  For example, #DE divide exception raising interrupt vector `0h`, or x87 FPU raising `10h` (https://wiki.osdev.org/IVT)

If a programmer intentionally or unintentionally makes the CPU raise those exceptions on its own, by running instructions like `bound` that can trigger a `BOUND Range Exceeded` exception, how does the BIOS or anything else distinguish that from an `INT 5` software interrupt to make as `PRINT SCREEN` call, for instance.  It's the same IVT entry so the same interrupt handler will be invoked for either case.

What's more, IRQ makes if you want to use keyboard you can't trigger those interrupts.  ([OSdev IRQ assignments table](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts#General_IBM-PC_Compatible_Interrupt_Information))

As so many Intel's default interrupt is remapped by the bios, things became unreasonable.

---

This was [cross-posted to retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24552/how-does-the-bios-distinguish-interrupt08h-12h-from-int-instructions-vs-actu?noredirect=1#comment80863_24552) and also has an answer there.

Comment: "what's inside it in those years": what's inside of *what*?

Comment: If you're asking about processors of 30+ years ago: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Erik Eidt Thanks, minutes ago I went to stackexchange but I can't find where to ask this question.

Comment: I don't know how to ask, what I meant is that why nobody found this obvious paradox nor any discussion about it.

Comment: If an interrupt occurs an interrupt handler can query the PIC to see if it was generated by an external IRQ (if not it can be assumed it was a processor exception) for those interrupts vectors that may overlap. The most common situation I remember was GPF and IRQ 5 mapping to the same interrupt vector and such a check in the interrupt handler was done so on demand unreal mode could be implemented on the 386+.

Comment: Of course this overlap issue wasn't created by Intel. Intel made it clear in the i88 apx manuals that everything from Interrupt vector 5 though 31 was reserved and IBM chose to map the PIC on the PC/XT to the reserved area at interrupt vector 8.

Comment: I made a major edit to your question to more clearly ask what Michael Petch and I think you're asking about.  (@ScottHunter: I removed that weird phrase, but I think that was trying to ask what was inside CPUs in those years.  Which is weird because this all still works on current CPUs in real mode.)

Comment: Back when IBM-AT(286) came out the BIOS itself didn't rely on the exceptions from 0x08 to 0x0f. It didn't really care and to be frank most DOS software didn't rely on them either. If they did they'd have to jump through hoops to find out where it originates (processor or external). I think back in the old days all the interrupt vectors that were unused were initialized with a pointer to code in the BIOS that simply did an IRET. It didn't really matter what they were initialized to. DOS would come along and initialize things as it saw fit including storing data in the interrupt table.

Comment: On a side note. The 8086 only used exceptions 0x00 to 0x04. The 286 introduced exceptions up to 0x0d.Things like the x87 exception (0x10) showed up in the 386. The defaults didn't raise this exception unless the x87 was reprogrammed. Any code that would use that exception would have to check where it came from to support both sofwtare `int 0x10` and the x87 floating point exception.

Comment: @Michael Petch ①If they check, how to check??②Did the BIOS manufacturer really check the interrupt type or they just avoid the clash after the 5H+ interrupt is assigned by Intel after 8086's successor? All the books I read didn't mention this, they just list the vector table or the interupt handling procedure. I am not only curious about this question itself, but more curious about why so many years nobody ever discuss such important and obvious interrupt handler clash in these years?! I can hardly found any article talk about this clash.

Comment: The BIOS never cared because it didn't use things that would cause these other exceptions. Code like a DOS program or a DOS device driver that may want to process both at the same time would have code written for it to handle this situation. And that code would replace or extend the existing BIOS routines. Extending usually involved chaining by redirecting the old interrupt handler to a new one that did some new processing (checking) and then eventually called the original handler.

Comment: When 80286 started use 4H+ interrupt , if BIOS then had to check the clash, they should realizes that they really shouldn't use the number what Intel‘s manual clearly refered "reserved", instead, they should use bigger number for them. But the fact is that, they seems totally ignored what Intel told them not to do and just do whatever they want, even it will cause clash, which is not logically. So I am presumming there must be something happed, either something I don't know(i.e. the bios check the source is external or internal) or the bios manufacturer just being unreasonable all these years

Comment: If you do digging creating interrupt handlers in real mode that do the switch have been documented but this is low level stuff. One person in particular that seems to discuss the on demand unreal mode issue and GFP exception and IRQ 5 overlapping can be found here https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC/blob/master/v0100/srclib/c0du.asm . Some of this low level stuff are things that may not be well documented, but we had to deal with back in the day. It may be hard to find it even on the itnernet unless you know software hacks that actually relied on it.

Comment: I provided a link to code that replaces IRQ5 so that it checks for whether the IRQ was external (from PIC) or not (if not assume it is a GPF #GP exception occurred)  did extra processing and eventually called the original interrupt vector.https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC/blob/master/v0100/srclib/c0du.asm . This kind of check can be applied to other overalpping IRQs and exceptions if need be. The cases where overlap occurred and caused issues for software were limited and weren't common.

Comment: In the code at the link provided the code of interest that does such a check is at label `___Int0xdIsr:`

Comment: @Michael Petch that link helps. Though it is seems rediculous. If they don't use the interrupt vector Intel clearly said "reserved", they don't need to check every time. IRQ 0(PIT) happened every 50+ ms means BIOS have to check it is PIT or Double fault every 60ms?

Comment: You only have to concern yourself with double fault if you happen to have to rely on it. Double Fault is not something that was dealt with in real mode for any situation I'm aware of. Software only has to engage in such a hack IF something produces and IRQ and they happen to be using an exception that overlaps. Most use cases didn't have a problem. I can't think of any use case where a Double Fault would be processed in real mode on 80286+ so there would not be a need for any software to do such a check.

Comment: The reality is that the oevrlap you are concerned about really didn't happen for most DOS or BIOS software. And the use cases for when it was an issue are rather limited so you won't find a lot of software that had to reprogram the real mode interrupt handlers to account for this. By the time you look at running DOS program on a 386 in Virtual 8086 mode this sin;t a problem because the protected mode OS can remap the PICs so the overlap doesn't exist and then can virtual deliver an interrupt wherever it wants to a v8086 task etc.

Comment: Regarding the BOUND instruction (which appeared on the 80186 and later processsors, not the 286 as I implied earlier) -  It was actually a known problem with some BIOSes that didn't do the checks. A failed BOUND check could freeze the computer doing repeated print screens. You had to live with it unless the interrupt handler was modified to deal with the issue later (like a DOS device driver or a BIOS upgrade/change). This is even noted in Ralph Brown's interrupt list http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0033.htm

Comment: This same question has a decent answer over here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24552/what-if-the-default-interrupt08h-12h-actually-happened-inside-the-cpu

Comment: When the IBM PC BIOS was first written, they were more concerned about not wasting 112 bytes of memory than about following some silly rule in the Intel specification.  Later  BIOSes (even to nearly present day) were concerned about backward compatible, so they couldn't change it even though they may have wanted to. Finally after 40 years we are starting to see most new systems without a legacy BIOS.

Answer (score 4):

> How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU?

Mostly it doesn't. It assumes interrupts 0x08 to 0x0F are IRQs (from PIC chip/devices); does nothing useful when the interrupt is a software interrupt (and sends an EOI to PIC chip that can cause problems in some cases); and crashes and/or locks up (via. an "exception -> return to faulty code -> exception -> return to faulty code ..." loop) when its an exception.

In theory it's possible to ask the corresponding PIC chip if there's an IRQ in service to tell the difference between a real IRQ and other causes (software interrupt, exception and "spurious IRQ 7 or 15"); and also possible to examine the bytes at "return CS:IP" to tell the difference between a software interrupt and other causes (exception, spurious IRQ). There is no "exception 0x0F" (it's reserved); so this set of "possible in theory" covers all of the cases.

Nobody does it.

An OS solves the problem by reconfiguring the PIC chip and/or IO APIC to ensure there's no conflicts between exceptions and IRQs, and using privilege levels to ensure that a software interrupt for interrupts used by exceptions or IRQs cause a general protection fault.

Comment: himem.sys v2.03+ on a 386+ used the method of checking the PIC to multiplex #GP (interrupt 0x0d) and IRQ 5 (interrupt 0x0d) to support on demand unreal mode.